# Citymapper URL Ignoring ArriveBy Parameter

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, citymapper-api

I'm building a simple "Launch in Citymapper" feature for an events app using their [URL parameters](https://citymapper.com/tools/1053/launch-citymapper-for-directions). I can get everything working except for `arriveby`, which never seems to do anything.

I've tried using real values from our API as well as hard coding Dates, and ensured that the date and time are both URI encoded and in the correct ISO-8601 format. I've even tried copy/pasting the example in their own documentation, but it never seems to make a difference.

Here's my code (both with/without hard coding):

```
`https://citymapper.com/directions?endcoord=${map.lat}%2C${map.lng}&endname=${encodeURI(sponsor.label)}&endaddress=${encodeURI(map.address)}&arriveby=${encodeURI(map.datetime)}`

`https://citymapper.com/directions?endcoord=${map.lat}%2C${map.lng}&endname=${encodeURI(sponsor.label)}&endaddress=${encodeURI(map.address)}&arriveby=2019-08-06T21%3A00%2B01%3A00`
```

Has anyone else ever managed to get this feature to work? I can't find any examples online, so starting to wonder if it's on their end? FWIW the app is built using Gatsby/React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your time with my own start (Green Park) and end points (Angel) it looks like your arrive by value will set the arrival time but not the day. Looking at this more closely it looks like it might be because it is more than six days in the future.

This is the URL:

```
https://citymapper.com/directions?endcoord=51.532499%2C-0.10579&endname=Angel&startcoord=51.50685%2C-0.142927&startname=Green+Park&arriveby=2019-08-06T21%3A00%2B01%3A00
```

If I change the time so it's less than 6 days in the future it sets the day properly but it still doesn't seem to provide any results. If I look out how the url looks when I'm set the arrival time using the UI the url that's generated doesn't have and `arriveby` but it does have an `arrival_time` and the time format is UTC rather than with an offset `2019-08-01T20%3A00%3A00.000Z`. Trying it out with the `arriveby` and `arrival_time` param using a UTC time stamp it seems to work every time. It might be worth using a UTC timestamp rather than one with a timezone offset?

I've tried this again this morning (31 July 2019) and it appears that the page is now working with offsets as well as UTC times.

Comment: Thanks for the response, looks like you uncovered a couple of different elements. Yes, it seems that you can't expect `arriveby` to work until six days before hand, which is fine. However, some further testing seems to imply that `arriveby` gets removed when you enter a start location (i.e. one is not specified in the original URL), which is why I couldn't see it populating at all.

Comment: Having spent some more time playing around with this I've confirmed all of the above. Basically I can't do what I want to (at the moment) without additional services. With that in mind, I'm accepting @Ben's answer as it got me on the right track.